# Why are log entries stored as both tuples and bloom filter in the Transaction Receipts Trie

Tags: logs, yellow-paper, receipts, bloom-filter

Gavin Wood's [Yellow paper](http://gavwood.com/Paper.pdf) describes the a transaction receipt (p5, sec 4.3.1):

> The transaction receipt is a tuple of four items com- prising the
>   post-transaction state, R_sigma, the cumulative gas used in the block
>   containing the transaction receipt as of immediately after the
>   transaction has happened, Ru, the set of logs created through
>   execution of the transaction, Rl and the Bloom filter composed from
>   information in those logs, Rb:

R = (R_sigma;Ru;Rb;Rl)

**Why is a Bloom filter used here for Rb?**